# How to configure commit id while doing Deployment using VSTS and ANT (SALESFORCE)

Tags: deployment, ant, salesforce, azure-devops

I have created VSTS build job using ANT. I have performed following steps.

1. Pulled everything from my Production Environment using retrieve
   functionality through ANT.
2. Set up Source Control with production code using GIT in VSTS
   successfully.
3. Created DEVELOP branch for development and changes.
4. Commit and Pushed all the changes to develop branch.
5. Now my source folder "src" of develop branch has everything means
   (Production + Develop changes)

I tried to run build against one of the sandbox using develop branch but limited Package.xml having components those are changed in development.

Getting following Error.

[BUILD ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGYH.png)

Now the thing is I know everything is in my develop branch but very specific package.xml is defined because I want to deploy specific components not all.

Any help to solve this issue?? Or anyway where we can PULL the source/FILE/Component by mentioning the commit id like from this commit onward etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Or anyway where we can PULL the source/FILE/Component by mentioning
>   the commit id like from this commit onward etc.

You can clean the working directory of the git repo firstly, and then get the changed files after a certain commit. Finally, checkout the changed files in git working directory, so that only the changed files are kept in git repo.

Detail steps as below:

1. **Clean all the files of the working directory in git repo**

   ```
   git rm -rf .
   ```
2. **Get the changed files after a certain commit**

   ```
   git diff <commit> <current branch name> --name-only
   ```
3. `Get the changed file into working directory`

   ```
   git checkout HEAD -- <filename>
   ```

Assume you want to keep the files which changed on `develop` branch only (after `master` branch at commit `4c671`), then the example shell script as below:

```
git rm -rf .
for t in $(git diff 4c671 develop --name-only) 
do
{
  echo "changed file $t"
  git checkout HEAD -- $t
}
done
```

Or

```
git rm -rf .
for t in $(git diff master develop --name-only) 
do
{
  echo "changed file $t"
  git checkout HEAD -- $t
}
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Package.xml is fine, it is already limited and having only components changed in the development cycle. The issue is Develop branch created from Master and have everything in there when I try to deploy I get error that SRC folder has files those are not mentioned in "Package.xml" I don't want to deploy everything again only the changed component. I am wondering is there any way that can pull only change source/component from develop branch after specific commit then I would not have this issue as source would be same as package.xml. Hope this will help.

Comment: @user9794112 I updated my answer with detail steps to keep the changed files after a certain commit. You can have a try.